# Why don't oppositely charged ends of separate batteries and capacitors produce current flow?

Tags: batteries, capacitor, physics

I have a question here regarding the flow of current from charges.

I understand if you connect a simple circuit to a battery it creates surface charges which allow the current to flow.

My questions are the following:
If I connect one end of 2 batteries together in series (positive of one battery to negative of other) and this is without any circuit, why does no current flow between the positive terminal of battery one and the negative terminal of battery 2?
[image: 2 batteries connected]

Similarly, if I connect 2 charged capacitors together from the positive side of capacitor 1 to the negative side of capacitor 2 without any other connecting circuit, why are surface charges not produced to allow current flow? (I understand there may be some electron flow while the wire is being polarized but after this the potential isnt dissipated)
[image: Capacitors in series without connecting circuit]

I'm clearly thinking of this wrong so I just want someone to point me into the right direction to help me conceptualize these answers

Edit:

I had a read through all the answers and I think I've sort of figured this out based on what Trevor_G said in a post someone likened to mine post. It seems like there is a surplus of positive ions on the positive terminal and a surplus of negative ions on the negative terminal however overall the battery as an entirety has a zero net charge. Similar to the way an atom with equal protons and neutrons has a zero net charge. Because there is no net charge (no surplus of charged ions) on the battery as an entirety they do not leave the battery, they are attracted to each other due to the electromagnetic field, but cannot reach each other cause the battery electrode is insulated (similarly to the way the ions on a capacitor are separated by insulation)  Connecting 2 batteries together would be like putting 2 net zero atoms together, they wont do anything.  The only way I could think to make the electrons leave the negative terminal of the battery would be the use a very high positive potential to pull them away from the battery's electro magnetic force using something (similar to the highly positively charged anode on an electron gun) to pull the electrons away, leaving the battery with an overall positive net charge. If this is theoretically possible the battery would lose its energy fast as there is no electrons going back in to combine with the manganese oxide and water molecule in the cathode so no new electrons will be made.

Comment: In reality a very small number of electrons will flow as you describe and the left battery will build up a tiny positive charge and right battery will build up a tiny negative charge - but then, the electrons are attracted back to left battery, because it is positively charged, and this stops them from flowing. The only way to solve this problem is to make charges move around loops, so there is no buildup.

Answer (score 1):

Current requires a closed circuit to flow.

If you have a single battery connected to nowhere, no current flows.

If you have a single battery connected to anywhere with one wire only, be it a load or another battery, no current flows.

The two batteries are two individual and separate floating voltage sources, they have no defined voltage reference between each other, until you choose to connect them somehow together.

Connecting two batteries in series just makes a single battery with double the voltage of the single battery. That's how e.g. 9V and 12V batteries work.

Connecting two capacitors in series just makes a single capacitor, with double the voltage rating and half the capacitance of the single capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

Current flows in circuits, closed loops. You are showing two open-circuit scenarios. Keep in mind, voltage is a potential difference between two points in circuit. The potential is across the battery. You are analyzing the suggested situation as if the batteries and capacitors are creating static electricity -There is no net charge on the surface of the battery.

The connected junction between the two batteries has no voltage or no meaning with out reference to one of the other terminals - either +1.5 to the positive side, 0V to itself (same potential), or -1.5V to the negative side.

Don't think of the negative side of the battery as having an abundance of electrons and lacking protons (they are net zero with the same number of positive and negative charges) rather, consider the negative terminal as having a "pressure" behind it (WRT the positive). We call this pressure the electromotive force, or more commonly, voltage.

Assume that current DOES flow in your setup. Where does the current go? This implies that there will be an accumulation of charge in one of the batteries. But if there's a net charge in one of the batteries, the charges would just use the same wire to equalize. And now you are back to your premise, a contradiction.

Comment: Hi mate please see edit I made in question